# Is it possible to estimate the average convenience yield on brent crude oil for 2018?

Tags: futures, yield

If it is possible to estimate it, how does one do this, and what is it?

Comment: You could look at the spot oil price in cushing (i.e. [here](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/RWTCD.htm)) vs the wti futures prices and calculate the convenience yield each day. The exchanges also now have *storage futures* which you could potentially extract some information from, though they are not liquid yet (if they ever will be, they seem to have a habit of creating underlyings just so they can do press releases, even if they end up rarely if ever trading...).